# find the index of the team with just one win

Tags: indexing, find

I'm stuck on a problem here. I'm trying to get the team with just one win and return its index. If there are multiple teams I should return the one occuring first else return -1. The teams are marked a to z.

I tried assigning the variables but it keeps giving me an error.

I tried assigning the variables but it still brought an error

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.